# ENOSYS error for pthread_create in Vxworks RTP project

Tags: c, vxworks

Below is the simple code I used to test thread functionality in RTP project of Vxworks

```
#define NUM_THREADS 2 

void *PrintHello(void *threadid) 
{ 
    long tid = 0;   
    tid = (long)threadid;
    printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
    return NULL;
} 

int main ()
{ 
  int rc;   
  long t;   
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];   
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&attr);

  for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)  
  {     
    printf("In main: creating thread is : %ld\n", t);   
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], &attr, PrintHello, (void *)t); 
    if (rc) printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is : %d\n", rc);   
    //pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);    
  } 
  pthread_exit(NULL);   
  return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
In main: creating thread is : 0 ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is : 71 
In main: creating thread is : 1 ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is : 71
```

Error '71' points corresponds to 'ENOSYS' errorcode and based on the search found that POSIX thread component is not enabled in the Vxworks kernel.

[vxWorks pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760846/vxworks-pthreads) post also related to this. But I am not sure in which file I need to enable the 'INCLUDE_POSIX_PTHREAD_SCHEDULER' component (configRtp.mk/*.cdf file ). 
Kindly provide detailed steps on how to add POSIX thread component to kernel

Answer (score 1):

You add components to the kernel by modifying the kernel configuration. The easiest way to do this is in workbench is by opening the VxWorks Image Project, and double-click on "Kernel Configuration". This should launch the Componenent Configuration Editor, as shown below.

You can use Find (Ctrl-F, on windows at least) to search by component name.

[image: Component Configuration]